# Chrome Dev Tools Viewport Width Different (Resizing Window Value vs Device Toolbar Value)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries

So I'm having a strange Chrome viewport issue that I've not had issues with before. 
 
 First: I am using Bootstrap 5 and thus it's breakpoints - to highlight my issue with a site that I'm working on we'll examine the 992px width breakpoint. Using this 992px value as the media query where my mobile menu would be triggered I have rules set within the following:  
`@media (max-width: 991.98px) {...}` 
 Looking at Chrome's Dev Tools' Device Toolbar you can see that the viewport correctly shows the mobile menu being triggered at a width of less than 992px (~991.98px)
[Desktop view 992px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF9U2.png)
 [Mobile Menu View 991px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YaJ1.png)

However when not using the Device Toolbar and just resizing the screen, which I find easier and my usual workflow when doing responsive edits, the viewport width seems to be off by 15px. Meaning my mobile menu breakpoint (in the resizing viewport width) seems to be triggered at 976px instead of 991px width - see attached photos. I've just notice this today and know it used to show the correct/same width value as when using the Device Toolbar. I'm wondering if I've changed some type of setting that I am unaware of. Note: my zoom value is default at 100% and my Chrome version is the latest official build Version 94.0.4606.54 (Official Build) (x86_64) 
 [Resizing Window Desktop View 977px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDPQS.jpg) 
 [Resizing Window Mobile Menu View 976px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG7p9.jpg)  
 Really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i also have this issue.
and i find my edge、 firefox also have this issue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmuI.jpg

above link is i use Edge open bootstrap5 website
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/features/
it breakpoint is 991px,
but the browser width is 976px still not change

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
  .row-cols-lg-3>* {
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     width: 33.3333333333%;
}
```

it still be influenced by that

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed with the new Chrome update today 11/24/21
Version 96.0.4664.55

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To the above point, do you have a bug report or GitHub issue or release notes you can link to that provides more details on this fix? That would make this answer more useful. That said, offering the date and patch number is certainly appreciated for its specificity.